# Gradle error: More than one variant of project :myModule matches the consumer attributes after upgrading to new Google Services

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

**Edit**: Seems to be a bug on Google side. Bug report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79235243

---

Since Google released the new changes (), I had to update google services. Once I did, I get this gradle error:

```
More than one variant of project :myModule matches the consumer attributes:
  - Configuration ':myModule:debugApiElements' variant android-aidl:
      - Found artifactType 'android-aidl' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
      - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
  - Configuration ':myModule:debugApiElements' variant android-classes:
      - Found artifactType 'android-classes' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
      - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
  - Configuration ':myModule:debugApiElements' variant android-manifest:
      - Found artifactType 'android-manifest' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
      - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
  - Configuration ':myModule:debugApiElements' variant android-renderscript:
      - Found artifactType 'android-renderscript' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
      - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
  - Configuration ':myModule:debugApiElements' variant jar:
      - Found artifactType 'jar' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
      - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
```

Here is the Project's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{
      url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
    maven {
      url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post ```myModule``` build.gradle?

Comment: It seems to be an issue coming from the latest com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0 library.
They probably haven't tested it with projects with more than one module.

Comment: This happened due to https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html.

Answer (score 13):

I had exactly the same issue and found the answer to be to change  the syntax of the offending module reference as follows:

**Previous Implementation:**

> compile project(':myModule')

**Current Implementation:**

> compile project(path: ':linkedin-sdk', configuration: 'default')

thanks...

Thanks to https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client/issues/57

Answer (score 5):

I did not update the services, but I got the same problem. I spent 5 hours looking for a solution. Fixed only this way.

Try to set

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

instead of

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
```

It's helped in my case, but I don't know the cause of the error.

Comment: Yea that works but I was hoping to not downgrade. Do you think it's a bug on their end?

Comment: 98% i don't change my code, It should work, but it's not

Comment: This resolved the issue for me. It seems that 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0' and 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1' may have a bug or a changed interface that has not been explained.

Comment: bug report here incase you were looking for it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79235243

Comment: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'` works for me

Comment: @SteveStrates Thank you. The same worked for me after searching for 3hrs. Your find helped me too.